# string from Sql database is question marks C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, telegram

im trying to message to user string that is hebrew lang from database the code is works fine but when its stored to data all the chars are question marks

```
zx = user photo id its not a hebrew string works perfect .
cap = e.Message.Caption.ToString();
usern = userid in table works perect to.

con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("update Accs2 set PhotoId = '" + zx + "',
                PhotoCap= '" + cap  + "' where Username like '%" + usern + "%'", con))
                {
                   await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                   await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(cid, "Your Photo And Caption Saved!", parseMode: ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: exit);

                 }
                con.Close();
```

Comment: Please don't ever generate SQL queries by concatenating strings. Use parameterized queries instead. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Using SqlParameter might solve your problem (if I understood it right).

Comment: Sorry I've not dealt with this but I thought I had seen somewhere that you need to prefix N' to the string that you're storing with ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of column to NVARCHAR where it stored in DB for example:

Old Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE (
COL_1 VARCHAR(10)
COL_2 VARCHAR(500),
...
COL_N VARCHAR(10)
);
```

And you are storing the message in column "COL_2" then change it to NVARCHAR as:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    COL_1 VARCHAR(10)
    COL_2 NVARCHAR(500),
    ...
    COL_N VARCHAR(10)
    );
```

I guess, the message is coming in language which current character set of the column is not supporting.

## EDIT - 1 : Updated with example solution

Here is the working set for my system, I have also changed the table character set and collation as below, then it works fine.

```
mysql> create table test_emoji(col1 int, str_with_emoji varchar(200)) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)

mysql> insert into test_emoji(col1,str_with_emoji) values (1,'dhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> select * from test_emoji;
+------+---------------------------------------------+
| col1 | str_with_emoji                              |
+------+---------------------------------------------+
|    1 | dhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌                      |
+------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT-2: In SQL Server:
You have to use a 'N' prefix before string as below outside the actual string:

```
insert into test_emoji(col1,str_with_emoji) values (1,N'dhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌');
```

Comment: yes the user string is hebrew and emujis from iphone/android , when the table update string saved in database as question marks

Comment: @MatanMalka : okay got it, modified my answer with EDIT-1 that is working example. all you need to do is change your character set and collation of table.

Comment: this its my table structure 

'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts]
(
 [Username] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 [ChatId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
 [PhotoId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
 [PhotoCap] NVARCHAR(500)  NULL ,
 [MessageId] NVARCHAR(255) NULL
 
)' @vivek

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Im using sql server sir

Comment: You can just put an "N" before the string as: insert into test_emoji(col1,str_with_emoji) values (1,N'dhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌');